# Script Manager in SharePoint pages

Tags: web-part, javascript, mobile

I am working on some mobile web parts and have got into a problem.

My issue is that I have a custom web part which is a mobile web part.  I have got everything working and I can see the web part in the SharePoint mobile pages.  I want to have an update panel in my web part and for that I added the scriptmanager on the user control web part.

Now when I see my web part on the page I get an error Object reference not set to an instance of an object.  If I remove the update panel and script manager, everything is working fine as expected.  So if someone can tell me how can I get script manager running in a SharePoint mobile page I would really appreciate it.

The page which SharePoint uses to display mobile web parts is mblwp.aspx and I guess there is no master page in mobile pages.

Answer (score 2):

Try adding the following to the CreateChildControls override of your user control code-behind:

```
    if (System.Web.UI.ScriptManager.GetCurrent(this.Page) == null)
    {
        System.Web.UI.ScriptManager scriptMgr = new System.Web.UI.ScriptManager();
        this.Controls.AddAt(0, scriptMgr);
    }
```

...before `base.CreateChildControls();`

Should cause the script manager to be added correctly, but only if one is not already present.  If that doesn't work, try:

```
this.Page.Form.Controls.Add(scriptMgr);
```

in place of:

```
this.Controls.AddAt(0, scriptMgr);
```

Hope that does the trick.